# CSS replacement for text-align in percentage

Tags: html, css, text-align

Sticky speaking here's the question itself:
Is there any property in CSS3 that alows to place some elements like `<p>` or any of `<h$>` like `text-align` but in percentage.

For instance HTML code:

```
<p id="first">Here's first P</p>
<p id="second">Here's second P</p>
```

and its style:

```
    <style>
        #first {
        margin-left: 50%;
        }
        #second {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
```

It doesn't look the same in different width. Is there any property like `background-position` but for such elements as introduced above?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here. Please explain what doesn't work with the example you gave.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? Are you asking how to indent text within an element by a percentage amount or how to center the elements themselves within their parent?

Comment: If you want to center horizontally, use `text-align` (inline or inline-block elements) or `margin: 0 auto;` (block elements). You could aswell do some calculation (margin-left = (container width - element width)/2 ) but that would be unnecessary overhead...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `text-ident`  to ident your text

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
#first {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block; (this is optional)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)** with percentage, but in your case the main problem is that you are using `<p>` elements which make a new paragraph automatically, if you replace it with `<span>` you can test the percentage, here's the code:

```css
#first {
       // margin-left: 50%;
}
#second {
        vertical-align:30%;
}
#third {
        vertical-align:50%;
}
#fourth {
        vertical-align:80%;
}

#cont{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="cont">
    <span id="first">Here's first P</span>
    <span id="second">Here's second P</span>
    <span id="third">Here's third P</span>
    <span id="fourth">Here's fourth P</span>
  </div>
```

You can see the example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=50%25)

Comment: Why 30%? just a random figure ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the translate property (using vw units (view width units)).

```css
#first {
  transform: translateX(20vw);
  display: inline-block;
}
#second {
  transform: translateX(30vw);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">Here's first P</p>
<br/>
<p id="second">Here's second P</p>
```

[browser prefixing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) removed for simplicity.

In this specific case, I have used vw units since my parent is the 'body' (whos width is 100% of screen). So 1vw = 1% in this case.